# Как сделать прозрачность при наложении блока?

Tags: html, css

Есть поле ввода. На поле ввода с абсолютным позиционированием налаживается `label`.
Сейчас у `label` задан фон, чтобы перекрывать верхнюю обводку поля ввода. Можно ли как-то сделать прозрачность под блоком `label`, не задавая фона? А то выглядит не очень.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.inp-form {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  border: 1px solid #397CFF;
  border-radius: 28px;
  background: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  user-select: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
}

.label {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: #052057;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #397cff;
  cursor: text;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form__row">
  <input class="email-input inp-form" id="email-input" type="text" name="email" required="">
  <label for="email-input" class="label">Email</label>
</div>
```

Comment: для .label -> background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); - 50% прозрачность или background-color: transparent; - 100%

Comment: Это тот же самый фон, теперь будет не синий, а черный с полупрозрачностью.

Comment: transparent не работает?

Comment: При чем тут transparent? При фоне transparent будет просто label, а под ним линия инпута.

Comment: Вы же сами писали "прозрачность при наложении блока" :))

Comment: Написано - прозрачность ПОД БЛОКОМ label, чтобы не  было видно обводки инпута без задавания фона лейблу.

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов - использовать `fieldset` + `legend`

Пример

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 3rem;
  background: #00f url(https://placeimg.com/1000/1000/arch) no-repeat center top / cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.form__row {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.form__fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #397CFF;
  border-radius: 28px;
}

.form__legend {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #397cff;
  cursor: text;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.form__input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  user-select: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form__row">
  <fieldset class="form__fieldset">
    <legend class="form__legend"><label for="email">Email</label></legend>
    <input class="form__input" type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="form__row">
  <fieldset class="form__fieldset">
    <legend class="form__legend"><label for="tel">Long text text text</label></legend>
    <input class="form__input" type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" required>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```